# Insert Google Scholar icon via Overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf

I want to insert the Google Scholar icon in my CV using Overleaf.com. The way I coded as follow:

```
\usepackage{academicons}

...

\makefield{\aiGoogleScholar}{\url{https://scholar.google.com.tw/myscholarexample}}
```

However, it did not work.

Could someone help me to solve the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile it with xelatex. you can change the compiler in overleaf under the menu.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works well!

Answer (score 0):

This can enable any sort of code

```
 \extrainfo{
        \faGithub\href{https://scholar.com/xyz}{ GoogleScholar} \quad
        \faLinkedin\href{https://www.linkedin.com/abc/}{ Linkedin} \quad
        \faSkype\href{https://skype.com/abc}{Skype}
        }
```